# Using Pandas & Pivot table how to use column(level) groupby sum values for the next steps analysis?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot

I want to find out how many sample will be taken from each level using proportion allocation method.

I have total 3 level's : [Small , Medium , Large ].

First , I want to take a sum for this 3 level's.

Next, I want to find out probability for this 3 levels

Next, I want to use this probability answer with multiply by how many samples given for this 3 levels

And, Last step is : sample will be select as top village's for the each level.

Data :

```
Village     Workers       Level
Aagar       10            Small
Dhagewadi   32            Small
Sherewadi   34            Small
Shindwad    42            Small
Dhokari     84            Medium
Khanapur    65            Medium
Ambikanagar 45            Medium
Takali      127           Large
Gardhani    122           Large
Pi.Khand    120           Large
Pangri      105           Large
```

let me explain, I am attaching excel photo

[image]

In the first step: I want to get sum values for level -> Small, Medium and High.  i.e ( 10+32+34+42)=118 for Small level.

[image]

In the next step I want to find out probability for each levels rounding in 2 decimal.
i.e ( 118/786) =0.15 for small level.

[image]

And using length(size) of each level multiply by probability for find out how many sample(village) taken from each level.

i.e for Medium level we have probability  0.25 , and we have 3 villages in Medium level. so, 0.25*3 = 0.75 will be sample taken from medium level.
So, it will rounding to the next whole number 0.75 ~ 1 sample taken from Medium level, and it will take top village in this level. so, in medium level "Dhokri" village will be select,

I have done some work,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv("/home/desktop/Desktop/t.csv")
df = df.sort('Workers', ascending=True)            
df['level'] = pd.qcut(df['Workers'], 3, ['Small','Medium','Large'])
df
```

I am use this command for get the sum for level's. next what to do I am confuse,

> > > df=df.groupby(['level'])['Workers'].aggregate(['sum']).unstack()

Is it possible in python , to get that village name what I get in the using excel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

- [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `sum` for same length of column
- divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) with `sum` and [`round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html)
- another `transform` with `size`
- last custom function

---

```
df['Sum_Level_wise'] = df.groupby('Level')['Workers'].transform('sum')
df['Probability'] = df['Sum_Level_wise'].div(df['Workers'].sum()).round(2)
df['Sample'] = df['Probability'] * df.groupby('Level')['Workers'].transform('size')
df['Selected villages'] = df['Sample'].apply(np.ceil).astype(int)

df['Selected village'] = df.groupby('Level')
                           .apply(lambda x: x['Village'].head(x['Selected villages'].iat[0]))
                           .reset_index(level=0)['Village']
df['Selected village'] = df['Selected village'].fillna('')
print (df)
        Village  Workers   Level  Sum_Level_wise  Probability  Sample  \
0         Aagar       10   Small             118         0.15    0.60   
1     Dhagewadi       32   Small             118         0.15    0.60   
2     Sherewadi       34   Small             118         0.15    0.60   
3      Shindwad       42   Small             118         0.15    0.60   
4       Dhokari       84  Medium             194         0.25    0.75   
5      Khanapur       65  Medium             194         0.25    0.75   
6   Ambikanagar       45  Medium             194         0.25    0.75   
7        Takali      127   Large             474         0.60    2.40   
8      Gardhani      122   Large             474         0.60    2.40   
9      Pi.Khand      120   Large             474         0.60    2.40   
10       Pangri      105   Large             474         0.60    2.40   

    Selected villages Selected village  
0                   1            Aagar  
1                   1                   
2                   1                   
3                   1                   
4                   1          Dhokari  
5                   1                   
6                   1                   
7                   3           Takali  
8                   3         Gardhani  
9                   3         Pi.Khand  
10                  3
```

You can try debug with custom function:

```
def f(x):
    a = x['Village'].head(x['Selected villages'].iat[0])
    print (x['Village'])
    print (a)
    if (len(x) < len(a)):
        print ('original village cannot be filled to Selected village, because length is higher')
    return a

df['Selected village'] = df.groupby('Level').apply(f).reset_index(level=0)['Village']
df['Selected village'] = df['Selected village'].fillna('')
```

Comment: in pandas no option for the merge as a center, like excel, one single value for level ?

Comment: No, I think no.

Comment: oh, okay, thanks for the information, and thanks for once again helps for me.

Comment: There is one exception, If have MultiIndex then all columns are concanecated together, but in your data it is impossible.

Comment: df['selected village']  = df.groupby() ... this line not works,give me error  :      raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: I think there is problem with data, give me a sec, I edit answer.

Comment: Super, I hope find problem quickly. ;)

Comment: Sir , can you please  help me on my other question.   Here is my question.                                                                                 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130337/using-pandas-numpy-how-to-use-column-data-page-break-for-generate-a-pdf

Comment: Really problematic help you, because never generate pdf :(

Comment: ,oh , if not pdf then , if possible .xlsx file generate ? For example : Jamkhed taluka - Crop1 data display only on Sheet 1,

for Jamkhed taluka -Crop2 data display on next Sheet .

for Jamkhed taluka - Crop3 data display on Sheet-3. so on?